# How to set text in overridden Card component?

Tags: aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I have a component based on Card.  It has a text field property in it called "Name".  What I am trying to do is change the text content of "Name".

Here is some example code where I can access the text color property, but my real goal is to change the content to `item.title` in the Collection list.

What's the best approach?

```js
export const DefaultCollectionExample = () => {
    return (
        <Collection
            type="list"
            items={[
                {
                    title: 'foo',
                },
                {
                    title: 'bar',
                },
                {
                    title: 'baz',
                },
            ]}
            gap="1.5rem"
        >
            {(item, index) => (
                <ScrollCard
                    key={index}
                    padding="1rem"
                overrides={
                    {
                        "Name": {
                            color: "red",
                        }
                    }
                }/>
            )}
        </Collection>
    );
};
```